# using functions and functors interchangeably - C++

Tags: c++, stl

With algorithms such as `copy_if`, `count_if`, and many others, I can use either  a function or a functor interchangeably where a predicate is required.

However with `std::set`, I cannot pass a function in place of the comparison function parameter it takes. I have to pass a functor in this case. Why doesn't it accept a function?

```
bool myfunction (int lhs, int rhs) {
    cout << "myfunction\n";
    return true;
}

struct myfunctor {
    bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const {
        cout << "myfunctor\n";
        return true;
    }
};

std::set<int,myfunctor> first;  
std::set<int,myfunction> second;  // this does not compile.
```

Comment: Would you mind showing a [MCVE] when asking about such please.

Comment: @Open Kastle  yes that was a typo (while posting the query) corrected it. It still does not compile.

Comment: Note that it's not accepting a functor either: `myfunctor` is not a functor, it is a class whose instantiations are functors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why doesn't it accept a function?

That's because `std::set` second template argument is supposed to be a type. Specifically it's supposed to be the functor type for the comparison. You are passing a function (pointer), which is not a type.